# file.delete() returns false for some files

Tags: android

`file.delete()` function returns `false` for big files while the files are deleted properly.

```
import java.io.File 

public class Delete {
      File file = new File(file path, filename);
      boolean deleted == file.delete(); 
      if(deleted == true)  { 
           some code for delete related title 
      }
}
```

In this code `file.delete()` function returns `false` for some files but I don't know the reason. However, that file is actually deleted when I check it manually in my android device's local memory. Can anyone explain the reason for that behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

This line is erroneous

```
boolean deleted ==file.delete();
```

change it to

```
boolean deleted =file.delete();
```

**Update:** This is because big files take longer time so use this code instead

```
public class Delete {
      File file = new File(file path, filename);
      file.delete(); 
      if(!file.exist())  { 
           some code for delete related title 
      }
}
```

Comment: i change my coding for boolean deleted = file.delete(); but same error will occur

Answer (score 3):

Dont know what are you trying to do with this code

```
boolean deleted ==file.delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have take == (compare)operator instead of = so it was raise problem. try with single.

Comment: file was deleted but value is not assigned as true to the variable

Comment: @ingsaurabh i have change my statement